# Adding character at the beginning and end of a list of items

Tags: php

I have long a txt file list like this

```
dddd
ggggb
btbtgbgb
gtrbr
```

and I want each item to be like this:

```
'dddd'
'ggggb'
'btbtgbgb'
'gtrbr'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "'" . str_replace(' ', "' '", 'dddd ggggb btbtgbgb gtrbr') . "'";
// returns 'dddd' 'ggggb' 'btbtgbgb' 'gtrbr'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $str = "dddd ggggb btbtgbgb gtrbr";
    echo "'" . str_replace(' ', "' '", preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str)) . "'";
    //returns 'dddd' 'ggggb' 'btbtgbgb' 'gtrbr' and strips extra whitespace if ever your text file has extra whitespaces.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// load file into an array
$lines = file($textfile);
foreach  ($lines as $key => $line) {
        // add quotes and remove tailing newline
        $lines[$key] = "'".rtrim($line, "\n")."'";
}
print_r($lines);
```

Note: This will probably not scale very well.